# Issue with newline from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

In my Rails app, I was having issues with rendering a link_to because, for some reason, a new line is added through my link_to.  For example, when I try to create the link with:

```
<% byline = render :partial => "projects/author_byline", :locals => {:project => image.project, :source=>"home"} %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('byline : <%= byline %>');
</script>
```

I would get this in the console:

```
console.log('byline :   <a href="/users/scientiffic" class="author_link">scientiffic</a>
');
```

Which would lead to this error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

I tried using the method "squish" to get rid of the newline:

```
<% byline = render :partial => "projects/author_byline", :locals => {:project => image.project, :source=>"home"} %>
<script>
 $('.carousel-inner.featureSlides').append('<%=link_to image.project.title, project_path(image.project) %> by <%= byline.squish %>')
</script>
```

But when I try to incorporate the "squished" variable on my page, it doesn't get rendered as link:

[image]

How can I render the code correctly as a link while removing the new line?

Here is my partial author_byline:

```
<% num_users = project.users.count %>
<% project.users.order("username ASC").each_with_index do |user, index| %>
    <% if num_users > 2 && index == num_users-1 %> , and <% end %><%= link_to user.username, user_path(user), :class=> "author_link" %><% if num_users == 2 && index == 0 %> & <% elsif num_users > 2 && index != num_users-2 && index != num_users-1 %> , <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sanitize to remove new lines:

```
<% byline = render :partial => "projects/author_byline", :locals => {:project => image.project, :source=>"home"} %>

<script>
    $('.carousel-inner.featureSlides').append('..by <%= sanitize(byline.gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, "")) %>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dash at the end of the ERB tags where you don't want an empty line to be added. Like this `-%>`

```
<% num_users = project.users.count -%>
<% project.users.order("username ASC").each_with_index do |user, index| -%>
    <% if num_users > 2 && index == num_users-1 %> , and <% end %><%= link_to user.username, user_path(user), :class=> "author_link" %><% if num_users == 2 && index == 0 %> & <% elsif num_users > 2 && index != num_users-2 && index != num_users-1 %> , <% end %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: then perhaps you need to move all the code in a helper function, you'll have better control

Comment: looking at other examples, it seems like I might have to add this: "ERB.new(template, nil, '-')"  Where does this go, though?  does it go in the partial?